# Lion and PT9 Compatibility

Tags: pro-tools

Hey all!

Is anyone running PT9, beta or non-beta, on Lion OSX?

Any issues if so?

Thanks,
C3

Answer (score 2):

Hi, I've been running a non beta of PT9 on Lion for a few months with no issues.
Good luck

Answer (score 0):

According to multiple sites, there is no issue with PT9 and Lion. New OS here I come!

Comment: How did it turn out?

Comment: Will let you know soon! Upgrading in the next few days.